# String will not convert to JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, json, parsing

I have a string passed to through a variable.  I'm trying to convert it to a JSON so I can break it down, but I keep getting a JSON Parser Error.

This is the string passed to me (originally from an API, so it should be formatted correctly):

```
[{"FlightSegment"=>[{"DepartureAirport"=>{"LocationCode"=>"LAX"}, "ArrivalAirport"=>{"LocationCode"=>"FLL"}, "MarketingAirline"=>{"Code"=>"NK"}, "ArrivalTimeZone"=>{"GMTOffset"=>-4}, "TPA_Extensions"=>{"eTicket"=>{"Ind"=>true}}, "StopQuantity"=>0, "ElapsedTime"=>286, "ResBookDesigCode"=>"U", "MarriageGrp"=>"O", "Equipment"=>{"AirEquipType"=>319}, "DepartureDateTime"=>"2015-09-18T21:00:00", "ArrivalDateTime"=>"2015-09-19T04:46:00", "FlightNumber"=>310, "OnTimePerformance"=>{"Level"=>7}, "OperatingAirline"=>... it goes on for a while, but repeating itself.
```

and the code I'm trying to use:

```
<% parsed_list = JSON.parse(@body) %>
<%= parsed_list %>
```

Unfortunatley I keep getting an unexpected token:

```
399: unexpected token at '{"FlightSegment"=>[{"DepartureAirport"=>{"LocationCode"=>"LAX"}, "ArrivalAirport"=>{"LocationCode"=>"FLL"}, "MarketingAirline"=>{"Code"=>"NK"}, "ArrivalTimeZone"=>{"GMTOffset"=>-4}, "TPA_Extensions"=>{"eTicket"=>{"Ind"=>true}}, "StopQuantity"=>0, "ElapsedTime"=>286, "ResBookDesigCode"=>"U", "MarriageGrp"=>"O", "Equipment"=>{"AirEquipType"=>319}, "DepartureDateTime"=>"2015-09-18T21:00:00", "ArrivalDateTime"=>"2015-09-19T04:46:00", "FlightNumber"=>310, "OnTimePerformance"=>{"Level"=>7}, "OperatingAirline"=>{"FlightNumber"=>310, "Code"=>"NK"}, "DepartureTimeZone"=>{"GMTOffset"=>-7}}], "ElapsedTime"=>286}
```

Any thoughts? 
Thank you!

Comment: That string is not JSON, it's a ruby hash.

Comment: @victorkohl -  That's odd.  The documentation for the API this data comes from says it's sent as JSON.

Answer (score 0):

```
@body.to_json
```

As Victor says, it's not a json, it's ruby hash